# Why outside border of service area always unreasonable?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, service-area

In ArcGIS 10.1 Network Analyst, why results of service area are different if number of break points is changed?

For example, the grid is 300m*300m, I try to produce service area around a node.

settings are like this...

[image]
[image]

Then I got this result
[image]

then I **only change breaks to 300,600**, result:

[image]

Why the outside border is always in strange shape?

Why the **service areas of 600m** are different in these 2 cases?

I try to change polygon generation to "detailed", it still generate this kind of results.

Really confused, and I have problems understanding any service area result because of this.

Comment: Seems that this data is course, you need more detials like evaluators and impedance http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Types_of_evaluators_used_by_a_network/00470000000n000000/ & http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Service_area_analysis/004700000048000000/GUID-EC46F6F3-11A6-4CEC-B25F-D07C7BC39851/